# I want the source of this question? In which reference is there?

Tags: calculus, reference-request

I want the source of this question? In which reference is there?

> If $$\int_0^\pi \frac{\cos x}{(x+2)^2} dx = A,$$ Find $$\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\sin 2x}{x+1}dx$$
>   in terms of $A$.

Comment: Where dod you see this?

Answer (score -2):

I want the source of this question? In which reference is there?[image]

Comment: You should TeX your answers rather than post images.

Comment: There is a mistake in the work. In the second last sentence behind the integral sign ,the $(y+2)$ term ought to have a square on it